# Jquery ul Submenu slidetoggle issue

Tags: jquery

I'm building a shop using oscommerce and have a menu using an addon which displays an unordered list for the categories.
The UL list displays like so...

```
    <ul id='suckertree1'><li><a href='index.php?cPath=21'>Summer</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href='index.php?cPath=21_23'>Bikes</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_28'>E-Bikes</a></li>
           <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_27'>Mountainroad</a></li>
           <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_26'>Road Bikes&nbsp;(1)</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_24'>Clothing</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_28'>Gloves</a></li>
       <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_27'>Shoes</a></li>
       <li><a href='index.php?cPath=21_23_26'>Protection</a></li>
  </ul>

</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href='index.php?cPath=22'>Winter</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm using jquery to hide a portion of the menu. When you click on Bikes - it then displays the submenu of that.  The problem I have is, that the submenu links do not link, they close the menu again..

Here is my (terrible) jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li ul").hide();
    $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li ul").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Because of the limitations with this menu, I am unable to assign classes or ID's to the menu other than the #suckertree1 already in place.
How can I prevent the preventDefault() from effecting the submenu points? and also, clicking an item to only toggle the submenu below?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li ul").slideToggle();
```

Find the `<ul>` relatively, since it's beside the `<a>` you clicked that's pretty easy to get at using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), like this:

```
$(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
```

So it'd look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li ul").hide();
  $("ul#suckertree1 li ul li:has(ul) > a").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/chg9w/)

This also fixes the sub menu links working by using [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [the child selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).  What we're doing is only binding this handler to links that are in an `<li>` that *also* contain a `<ul>` element.  It if doesn't have one (no sub menu) this code doesn't even run for that anchor, and it just continues to follow it's `href` like normal.